# Xpath - finding sibiling

Tags: html, xpath

I want to find the parent and the sibiling of some nodes in a website (it xpath). My big problem is that I want to find a sibiling of node, with no Id, only by it attribute.

for example:
    `<a id="nav-europe-3231" class="" href="/EUROPE/" title="Europe News Headlines and Video from CNN.com International">Europe</a>`

```
 <a id="nav-asia-1265" class="" href="/ASIA/" title="Asia News Headlines and Video from CNN.com International">Asia</a>
```

I saw some instruction, like `parent::child-node`, but it doesn't find the xpath in this way.

How can I find the parents and the sibiling of this node?

Comment: Contradiction: You say that the the node "with no id", but in the provided example both elements have `id` attributes. Please, edit the question and correct. Please, provide complete XML document (as small as possible). Please, specify which exactly node from this document should be selected based on which exactly node.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 1 you can find the siblings and parent of the context node via the `preceding-sibling::` and `following-sibling::` axes (for siblings) and either `../` or `the`parent::` axe to find the parent.

Note that with axes you must specify a node name after the `::`. If you don't know it, you can use the wildcard, `*`.

See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: Therefore, `//a[@href='/EUROPE/']/following-sibling::a` will select the first `A` sibling of an `<a href="/EUROPE/">` element.

Comment: @Slanec: No, `//a[@href='/EUROPE/']/following-sibling::a` selects all following siblings of all `//a[@href='/EUROPE/']` elements.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Ooooh. Right. I got caught by the usual trap, again.